# jqGrid Toolbar Search Operands

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using the `filterToolbar` with the `stringResult` option set to `false` with search operators. The problem is it sends the values in the inputs but not the operands.`

`stringResult` set to false:
 [image]

`stringResult` set to true:
[image]

is there any way I can avoid using stringResults but get the operand data?

Comment: Format of request with `stringResult: false` option is very old. At it don't support any operator information. In which format you want to send the information? You don't posted any suggestions. In general you can use `beforeSearch` callback of `filterToolbar` to extend `postData` parameter of jqGrid with additional information, but the problem is that you should first **define** the format of data which will be good to interpret on the server side.

Comment: So the recommended method is really using stringResult? I guess I'll have to use it. Thanks!